# Numerical error with simulation of electric charge in homogeneous magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, simulations, numerical-method

So, I am trying to make an 2D animation of electric charge in homogeneous magnetic field which is perpendicular to charge's velocity.

I've got the "circular" motion but the problem is that the speed of charge is increasing within a field. It is a small increase which I assume that is the result of inaccurate numerical method.

I would like to show that speed of charge is constant and any help would be appreciated.

Here is the part of the loop which describes charge's motion

```
f = Magneticfield( x, y, Vx, Vy, Bz);

Vx += f.x * dt;
Vy += f.y * dt;

x += Vx*dt;
y += Vy*dt;
```

where

```
function Magneticfield( x, y, vx, vy, B){

    return{ x: B*vy, y: -B*vx};
```

Comment: You are right, this is a "feature" of simple numerical integrators. What you are using is the most simple and, unfortunately, in many cases least accurate (forward) Euler method. The easiest solution is to reduce the size of the time step. A better class of fairly straight forward numerical integration methods for differential equations are the Runge-Kutta methods http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods. Or, since in your case the energy is preserved, you may also try to normalize $v_x$ and $v_y$ after every step so that $v_x^2+v_y^2=2E_0/m$.

Comment: I just did a test with the simple forward Euler integrator (the code that you have) plus a step by step correction of the total kinetic energy. It's pleasantly surprising that even with dt=0.1, B=1, vx=1, vy=0 (which is very coarse time step), the circle doesn't seem to drift much, neither does the radius change. That's a rather cool demonstration of the strength of integrators which use readily available physics information about the system to increase accuracy. Thanks for asking! I had fun and it brought back memories of my very first computer. By the way, check out symplectic integrators!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am glad that my question brought some old memories :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am glad that my question brought some old memories :) The thing is that I'am making some kind of game and additional reduce of time step doesn't work well with the game speed. Normalization condition you've mentioned, if I understood correctly brings another loop in the story so that option also slows down the game a bit. I am trying to find the algorithm which brings the best ratio of game speed and physics law.

Comment: Speed can't be a problem in this case, can it? A modern CPU should be able to do 1e7-1e10 time steps per second for this loop (depending on your hardware - phone or server). Worst case you have to make multiple simulation steps per game step, which is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Can you please send me your code for the test that you've mentioned before (with correction of the total kinetic energy). Now, I think that I didn't understand your idea from the beginning. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation details of a computational task.

Comment: @Puibo: Initialize: vx=1;vy=0; Calculate kinetic energy: E0=(vx\*vx+vy\*vy)/2; In the loop update velocities: vx+=f.x\*dt; vy+=f.y\*dt; Normalize vx and vy to preserve kinetic energy: E=(vx\*vx+vy\*vy)/2; norm = sqrt(E/E0); vx=vx/norm; vy=vy/norm;. That's it. Now you can update x and y and you have eliminated the integrator error that changed the total kinetic energy.

Comment: Now I understand. This is brilliant! Thank you very much for your help. If you write this as an answer I will note it as solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your results using a forward difference integration are expected, and are resolved using the [Boris method/push](http://www.particleincell.com/blog/2011/vxb-rotation/), the "*de facto* standard for particle pushing in plasma simulation codes."

The below implementation in Python generates this plot of velocities for 10 periods (blue = forward difference, red = Boris method):

[image]

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# Constants
m = 9.1e-31
q = 1.6e-19
B = 1.0
omega = q*B/m
T = 2.0*math.pi/omega

# Initial conditions
Vx0 = 0.0
Vy0 = 1.0

# Time steps
steps = 1000
pts = steps + 1
dt = 10 * T / steps

Vx_F = zeros(shape=(pts,pts))
Vy_F = zeros(shape=(pts,pts))    
Vx_B = zeros(shape=(pts,pts))
Vy_B = zeros(shape=(pts,pts))

Vx_F[0] = Vx0
Vy_F[0] = Vy0
Vx_B[0] = Vx0
Vy_B[0] = Vy0

for i in range(1,steps+1):
  # Forward difference
  Vx_F[i] = Vx_F[i-1] + dt * omega * Vy_F[i-1]
  Vy_F[i] = Vy_F[i-1] - dt * omega * Vx_F[i-1]

  # Boris push
  t = q*dt*B/(2*m)

  VprimeX = Vx_B[i-1] + Vy_B[i-1] * t
  VprimeY = Vy_B[i-1] - Vx_B[i-1] * t

  s = 2.0*t/(1.0+pow(t,2.0))

  Vx_B[i] = Vx_B[i-1] + VprimeY * s
  Vy_B[i] = Vy_B[i-1] - VprimeX * s

plt.gca().set_color_cycle(['red', 'blue'])
plt.plot(Vx_B, Vy_B)
plt.plot(Vx_F, Vy_F)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Might be useful to include the relevant integration method, rather than simply provide the link.

Comment: Sure. I'll try to update my answer later today with more detail.

Comment: Thank your for your help, I understand the idea. Since I am making some kind of the game, I was looking for the method which requires smallest amount of variables. I am not sure if Boris method or normalization of speed (which CuriousOne pointed out) is more precise on long term but the idea of normalization of speed solved my problem. When my reputation goes +15, I am going to vote up your answer as well.